# SIKULI API - How to use type with special combination keys like ALT+TAB

Tags: api, sikuli

I started one application and I need acess another application with special combination keys like ALT+TAB.

I write the following code, but nothing happened:

```
DesktopKeyboard keyboard = new DesktopKeyboard();
keyboard.type("\ue022"+"\t");
```

I try to use key constants, but it does not work.

Comment: Swap the keys in `keyboard.type`. Also check [Sikuli ALT+TAB](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/104764)

Comment: Thanks Damian,

The command "type(Key.TAB, KEY_SHIFT)" work well in Sikuli IDE, but I use sikuli-api in a java program, the constants key.TAB and KEY_SHIFT does not exists.

Comment: Try this : `m_screen=new Screen();m_screen.type(Key.TAB,Key.SHIFT); `

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: `type(Key.TAB, KEY_SHIFT)` 
Here is also a link where you can find more information about how to use keys and key combinations in Sikuli: [Link](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html)